# Building Gate between house and garage with concrete slabs

Tags: concrete, fence, gates

We are fencing our backyard for the safety of our autistic son and what we have left is a gate between our house and the garage.

They do not line up evenly and there are concrete slabs and rocks in between. Were not sure what the best way is at this point for this gate. It's all we have left and struggling.

Were trying to figure out which way is best. Set posts or attach to house and which side should have more of the weight.
Any advice of best way would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added some. Trying to upload them has been slow.

Comment: Do you plan on securing it to both walls or leave it propped up against the walls?

Answer (score 1):

Your fence/gate does not need to be perpendicular with the walk. Run it straight between the corner of the house and the corner of the garage.

You will need one secure post on the concrete to allow for your gate. Build a triangle foot for that post and blue-bolt it to the concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this cheap and simple solution. Get two from HomeDepot and fasten the fence top rail to the wood wall.

[image]Home Depot